# How to tell when sshd is ready for connections?

Tags: bash, ssh, rhel

I use a bash script to reboot a remote server, then login via SSH to run some commands.  My script works most of the time, but occasionally fails with this error:

**"System is booting up. Unprivileged users are not permitted to log in yet. Please come back later. For technical details, see pam_nologin(8)."**

If I wait a few seconds and then try again it works fine.  I'm currently checking for connectivity like this:

```bash
while ! nc -z $HOST 22; do
  sleep 1
done

ssh $HOST '/opt/my script..sh'
```

Is there a better way to test connectivity that will ensure sshd is really ready for connections?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test that ssh is ready to accept connections and run commands, then use `ssh`, rather than something else like `nc`. For example:

```
while ! ssh $HOST true; do
  sleep 1
done
```

This will only return successfully if (a) you are able to successfully connect to the remote host and (b) run the `true` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the possibility of earlier `root` logins then you can simply delay the start of `sshd`.

Add this to the SSH service unit:

```
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
```

With that `sshd` is started only when unprivileged user logins are allowed.

This does not allow an earlier SSH login. It just reduced the SSH states from three to two: If you can talk to it at all then you can log in, too.